# creating a generic arraylist

Tags: java, generics

this is a 2 part question.

I have two classes: `Animal` and `Vehicle` which I'll be instantiating as objects. `Animal` contains two instance variables: `numLegs` and `animalName`, and `Vehicle` contains one instance variable: `numTires`, both classes contain getters and setters.

I have a generic class `Box` that holds either an `Animal` or a `Vehicle`.

Suppose I want to create an `Arraylist` of boxes. Every `Box` in said `Arraylist` will hold exclusively type `Animal` or exclusively type `Vehicle`.

e.g: In the case of exclusively animals, this will look something to the effect of:

```
List<Box<Animal>> list = new ArrayList<Box<Animal>>(); 
list.add( new Box<Animal>( new Animal( "fluffy", 4 ) ) );
```

(1). What should the box class look like?

also, suppose I want to perform a getter on an animal from the list. 
Such as: `System.out.println(list.get(0).getName());`

(2). how would I go about this properly?

Comment: Having a class that contains both `Animal` and `Vehicle` is just confusing. This is why you are having a hard time coming up with a good solution. If the two classes having a common class then just use that. If they have nothing in common then I suggest using a different list for each.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after, but if you're wanting a generically typed `Box` class, it probably needs to look something like this:

```
public class Box<T extends SuperclassOfAnimalAndVehicle> {
  T myModeOfTransport;

  Box(T myModeOfTransport) {
    this.myModeOfTransport = myModeOfTransport;
  }

  public T getModeOfTransport() {
    return myModeOfTransport;
  }
}
```

This line: `list.get(0).getName()` won't do however.  You'll have to get the object that `Box` contains.  So using my example, it would be `list.get(0).getModeOfTransport().getName()`, assuming `Vehicle` and `Animal` both have `getName()` methods.

All that being said, I'm really confused about why exactly this is necessary.  Perhaps if you explained the bigger picture I could give you a more complete answer.

Comment: okay, tyvm for the response. But in this case, what would SuperclassOfAnimalAndVehnicle look like? 
And wouldn't it be considered unprofessional to implement a method getName() in vehicle if vehicle had no name?

Comment: @StephenSiegel Like I said, I don't really even know what *`Box`* should look like.  Why does it exist?  What does it do?  No it's not good to add methods to objects just so they can share a superclass, but if you want a single generically typed `Box` class that can contain `Animal` and `Vehicle` that's what you have to do.  Like I said, if you give me some more info, I can give you a better idea about what you need to do.

Comment: @StephenSiegel: It's OK to have empty abstract parent class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a list containing two or more entities with nothing  in common then you will always need to specialize your code to address each of them. This `Box` class is completlly useless.

```
Object o = list.get(0);
if(o instanceof Animal) {
   System.out.println(((Animal)o).getName());
}
```